# Gauge transforms, gravitational waves, and the speed of thought

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory

The relation between Gauge theories and physical constants can be summed up as follows [1, verbatim]:

> In gauge theories, the physical content is gauge invarient: the physical properties of a configuration do not change under a gauge transformation...

Gravitational waves are physical entities which can be measured both indirectly (e.g. the Hulse and Taylor binary pulsar [2]) and recently directly (i.e. LIGO).

Let the presence of (linearized) physical gravitational waves depends on the Gauge chosen - you need to use the *harmonic gauge* else you simply get waves that travel at *the speed of thought*. Eddington had similar arguments in is 1923 book [3].

I am confused, therefore about the application of gauges here. Our choice of gauge changes the physics. You can choose one gauge and get gravitational waves traveling at the speed of light, but choose another and you don't [3] i.e. our gauge conditions don't seem like gauge conditions, but cause actual physical difference between solutions. Please can someone explain the resolution and how it is applicable to think of this situation.

**References**

[1] Hemker, P.W. and Wesseling, P. eds., 2012. Multigrid Methods IV: Proceedings of the Fourth European Multigrid Conference, Amsterdam, July 6–9, 1993 (Vol. 116). Birkhäuser. (p63)

[2] Weisberg, J.M. and Taylor, J.H., 2005, July. The
relativistic binary pulsar b1913+ 16: Thirty years
of observations and analysis.
 In
 Binary Radio
Pulsars
 (Vol. 328, p. 25).

[3] Eddington, A.S., 1930. Mathematical theory of relativity. General Books LLC.

Comment: Do you know what a gauge is?

Comment: @user121330 I have never studied them formally, but know how to make them in EM and GR along with the effect they have on the equations involved.

Comment: What is the the "speed of thought"?

Comment: 1. What is the "speed of thought"? 2. General relativity is not *exactly* a gauge theory like any other. You can reformulate it as a gauge theory of the Lorentz (or even the $\mathrm{GL}(N)$) group but the standard formulation is *not a gauge theory*. You can see this simply by noting that the gauge field should be the Christoffels yet outside the Palatini formulation the Christoffels are not considered dynamical. It is therefore unclear how the quote about gauge theories is supposed to be applicable to GR, in particular what the gauge transformations are.

Comment: @HughMungus I think they're saying the choice of gauge changes when an event happens.

Comment: @HughMungus Sorry, the speed of thought is a term (I think coined by Eddington). It basically means that the waves are 'waves' in the coordinate system and not of the physical space. I.e. they leave the Riemann tensor zero, they also do not travel at the speed of light but at another speed - called 'the speed of thought'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory - The first paragraph should be enough

Comment: @ACuriousMind See my last comment. From T.A.Moore *A General Relativity Workbook*,  we can perform a Guage transform in GR (at least in the linear limit) by $h'_{\mu \nu}=h_{\mu \nu}-\partial_\mu \zeta_\nu -\partial_\nu \zeta_\mu$ where $\zeta$ is any arbitrary 4-vector.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, the same thing occurs in E&M.   In the Coulomb gauge the potentials fill space instantaneously.  Retardation becomes apparent only when calculating fields with the proper transverse current.

Comment: @garyp I think you may be onto something useful. Please could you expand on it in an answer?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification I'm no expert, so I'll have to pass.  But I'll make an additional observation:  Gauges can be very non-intuitive.  For example, the transverse current needed for the Coulomb gauge is not localized to the location of charge density.  It actually fills all space.  It may be good for calculations, but it's not so good for physical insight.

Comment: @garyp By definition, a guage has no bearing on what ends up happening, so it's anybody's guess as to which guage represents what's 'actually' happening. I'd argue that after one understands the basics, one should examine **every** guage for physical insight.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer we are working in the linearized theory. Thus unless otherwise stated everything only holds to first order. Although I asked the question I have written the question in the style I would answer a question I had not asked (i.e. use of 'you' etc)

### The Meaning of a Gauge Transform in GR

Consider the two metrics: 
$$ g_{\mu \nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu}+h_{\mu \nu}$$
$$g'_{\mu \nu}=\eta+h_{\mu \nu}-\partial_\mu \xi_\nu-\partial_\nu \xi_\mu$$
where $\xi_\nu$ is an arbitary but small covector. It turns out that $g_{\mu \nu}$ and $g'_{\mu \nu}$ in the same coordinates have the same Riemann tensor and therefore satisfy the same Einstein equations. This means they correspond to the same stress-energy tensor and therefore the same physical solution. Thus by making the transformation: 
$$h_{\mu \nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu \nu}-\partial_\mu \xi_\nu-\partial_\nu \xi_\mu$$
$$x_\mu \rightarrow x_\mu$$
we leave this physical situation unchanged. Such a transformation, in this context is called a *gauge transformation*.

### The Speed of Thought

You said:

> Let the presence of (linearized) physical gravitational waves depends on the Gauge chosen - you need to use the harmonic gauge else you simply get waves that travel at the speed of thought.

This statement is not as general as you make out which can be proved by a simple argument:

---

Let $h_{\mu \nu}$ correspond to a physical gravitational wave (i.e. produces curvature) in the harmonic gauge then (to first order): 
$$h'_{\mu \nu}=h_{\mu \nu}-\partial_\mu \xi_\nu-\partial_\nu \xi_\mu$$
must also produce a physical gravitational wave but in general is not in the harmonic gauge.

---

Where your comment does apply is in the case of plane waves, as described [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/42/11662.full?sid=e318b62b-db28-4f2a-9f66-675b51f94730). If we take a solution of the form: 
$$h_{\mu \nu} =A_{\mu \nu} e^{ik_\rho x^\rho}$$
for some constant tensor $A_{\mu \nu}$. This only corresponds corresponds to a *physical* wave traveling at the speed of light if $h_{\mu \nu}$ is in the harmonic gauge, else it corresponds to a *coordinate* wave traveling at the 'speed of thought' (i.e. not the speed of light, and not a real wave). However, the metric with:
$$h'_{\mu \nu}=A_{\mu \nu} e^{ik_\rho x^\rho}-\partial_\mu \xi_\nu-\partial_\nu \xi_\mu$$
corresponds to the same physical wave and is not in the harmonic gauge - we just can't write it as a plane wave.

### Concluding Remarks

The crux of your question lays in the statement:

> You can choose one gauge and get gravitational waves traveling at the speed of light, but choose another and you don't [3] i.e. our gauge conditions don't seem like gauge conditions, but cause actual physical difference between solutions.

I hope I have convinced you that this statement is **false**. By changing gauge you change the form of the solution (i.e. from a nice plane wave to something nasty) but do not, and cannot change the physical content.